# Increase efficiency of nested for loops

Tags: python, json, for-loop, nested, python-requests

So I am iterating through some JSON data and it's very slow cause I am using nested for loops.

My code looks as follow:

```
import requests
import json


pokemon_url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/bulbasaur/'
pokemon_move_url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/pound/'
pokemon_info = requests.get(pokemon_url)
pokemon_data = pokemon_info.text
pokemon_parsed = json.loads(pokemon_data)


name = pokemon_parsed['forms'][0]['name']

for move in pokemon_parsed['moves']:
    for method in move['version_group_details']:
        if method['version_group']['name'] == 'sun-moon' and method['move_learn_method']['name'] == 'level-up':
            pokemon_move_url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/'+move['move']['name']
            pokemon_move = requests.get(pokemon_move_url)
            pokemon_move_text = pokemon_move.text
            pokemon_parsed_moves = json.loads(pokemon_move_text)
            print(method['move_learn_method']['name'],move['move']['name'],method['level_learned_at'],pokemon_parsed_moves['type']['name'],pokemon_parsed_moves['power'],pokemon_parsed_moves['accuracy'])
```

I would like to know how I can do this more efficiently and better. I know there is a better way, but I just started with Python so I am still learning.

Comment: "it's very slow cause I am using nested for loops" - no, it's slow because you do an http request on each iteration. That's the slow part, not the loops.

Comment: It _looks_ like `pokemon_move = requests.get(pokemon_move_url)` can be safely extracted from the inner loop (to the outer loop). Should speed things up considerably.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thank you very much, now I see what I did wrong and I can learn from it. This solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sergio mentions, the http request is probably slower than the for loops, but when you have a large amount of iterations, the for loop can slow things down as wel. You could try to build a list of urls using list comprehension and then do the request:
for the first line in the inner loop it would be:

```
pokemon_move_url = ['https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/'+move['move']['name'] for move in pokemon_parsed['moves'] for method in move['version_group_details'] if method['version_group']['name'] == 'sun-moon' and method['move_learn_method']['name'] == 'level-up']
pokemon_move = [requests.get(url) for url in pokemon_move_url]
pokemon_move_text = [move.text for move in pokemon_move]
pokemon_parsed_moves = [json.loads(text) for text in pokemon_move_text]
```

This should be significantly faster than using the for loops (depending of course if the for loop or the request is the bottleneck)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your code, only thing that I don't get working is the printing aspect. How should I do this with your code?

Comment: Try:

output = [method['move_learn_method']['name'],move['move']['name'],method['level_learned_at'],parsed_move['type']['name'],parsed_move['power'],parsed_move['accuracy']) for parsed_move in pokemon_parsed_moves]
print(output) 
this will print the list of all the desired prints.
To get all entries seperate you could try:
[print(entry) for entry in output]

I'm not a pro with list comprehensions but I think it should work.

Comment: @JtenBulte: this list comprehension, I very much doubt it will be _any_ faster than the for loops (it's the same loops with a pretty face), but now it also takes much more memory (need to build and store all the urls at once).

Comment: Ah thanks for this comment. I'm still rather new to Python and especially list comprehensions. I was told that is faster because it is compiled in C but your link says it's not.